# CSS body border not going all the way up to the top of the page due the a fixed header

Tags: header, border, fixed

I am trying to make the body border go up all the way to the top of the page, but because my header 'about' is fixed, the border is not going all the way up.

```
body {
  font-family: Gruppo;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #000000;
  border-right: 20px solid teal;
  border-left: 20px solid teal;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  right: 100px;
}
```

[site image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NQgl.png)

Comment: You could give your fixed header margin left and right the amount of the border or add a border there as well.

Comment: I tried those two things and nothing seemed to work. Here is a draft page ~ hope this link works. Thank you https://aria-olso-12.superhi.com

Comment: Ok more infos :) give your section.profile styles margin-top: 0; and use padding-top: 70px; instead